# How to update a child component that extends a parent class when the parent class updates?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, anti-patterns

I have a page that has a number of forms on it. In an effort to try and keep the forms consistent, I have a main `Form` class component that is extended by all the other forms.

This parent `Form` component has the logic in it to add field validation, along with adding secure tokens before and after the form fields:

**Parent Form**

```js
class Form extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }


   view(child) {
      
       return (
           <>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                 ... // extra form fields
                 
                 {child}     // 'actual' form fields, passed from child

                 ... // extra wrapper form fields
                 <button>Submit</button>
              </form>
           </>
       );

   }
}
export default Form;
```

**Child Form**

```js
class LoginForm extends Form {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             data: {} ... form-field specific data
         }
    }

    render() {
         return this.view(
             <>
                 <MyFormField name="field1" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur} field={this.state.data.field1} />
                 <MyFormField name="field2" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur} field={this.state.data.field2} />
                 <MyFormField name="field3" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur} field={this.state.data.field3} />             
             </>
         );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

The `LoginForm` (child) extends the parent `Form`, and in its `render` method, calls the `view` method of the parent. This effectively will render the pieces passed over with the parent handling validation and such.

The problem it is facing, is that when an update is performed on one of the fields, it is not updating the child (`LoginForm`) - so any field validation errors are not displaying, and so forth.

**Page**

```js
class MyPageComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="my-page">
                    <h2>header</h2>
                    <LoginForm />         // including LoginForm
                </div>
            </>
        );
}

export default MyPageComponent;
```

The `MyPageComponent` will create the layout, and then embed the form in the page wherever it may be. The embedded form, in this case - `LoginForm` will contain all the handlers for the validation, submission, state and all that of the form.

Is this an anti-pattern? I have not found anything so far to suggest so, but it is frustrating - and I cannot help but wonder if there is a better way to do this. The only part that strikes me as somewhat unconventional, is that the child's `render` method calls the parent classes `view` method.

My goal in all this is just to create a consistent handler for all the forms on the site that can easily be reused.

How do I get the `child/LoginForm` to update when it is updated in the parent `Form`? Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**
Updates to the state.data.field elements are the updates that I am referring to. These are updated by running `this.setState(newState)` on the `Form` component. Usually, a state change would trigger a render update?

Comment: *when an update is performed on one of the fields, it is not updating the child (LoginForm)* - aren't the fields in `LoginForm`? What updates do you mean? Can you show some code that is making the updates?

Comment: @Konrad added an edit update to the question, thanks